# Unable to fetch POST without no-cors in header

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

On making request like that:

```
return fetch(
            'http://localhost:8000/login',
            {   method: 'POST',
                headers: new Headers(
                   {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept":"application/json"}
                ),

                body: JSON.stringify(
                   {'name': 'Tom', 'password': 'Soyer'}
                )
             }
           ).then( response => { console.log(response);})
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

request running with method OPTIONS instead POST.
Only on adding mode: 'no-cors' request become POST:

```
return fetch(
            'http://localhost:8000/login',
            {   method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: new Headers(
                   {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept":"application/json"}
                ),
                body: JSON.stringify(
                   {'name': 'Tom', 'password': 'Soyer'}
                )
             }
           ).then( response => { console.log(response);})
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

but response not ok than (even if network response status is 200): {type: "opaque", url: "", status: 0, ok: false, statusText: ""…}
I suppose it because

> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data text/plain

described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Is any way bring to live POST json data with fetch?

Comment: Well, just a) don't make cross-domain http requests or b) answer them with the appropriate CORS headers

Comment: have you solved your issue..if yes, can you updated your answer..

Answer (score 48):

The custom `Content-Type` header you're sending causes your request to be preflighted, which means an OPTIONS request, containing some metadata about the POST request that is about to be dispatched, will be sent *before* the actual POST request.

Your server needs to be prepared to deal with this OPTIONS request. You haven't specified what the server is written in, but with express for example, you can register a middleware that intercepts all 'OPTIONS' requests, sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` headers, and responds with 200.

If it is possible for you to make the request using a 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' header, that would solve your problem. Alternatively you could use something that bypasses XHR entirely, like JSONP.

Answer (score 17):

When using `non-cors`, all headers must be valid *simple-headers*. The only valid values for the `content-type` header that qualifies as a *simple-header* is:

```
headers: [
  ['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
  ['Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'],
  ['Content-Type', 'text/plain'],
]
```

**Exceptions with contingencies:**

```
headers: [
  ['Content-Type', 'application/csp-report'],
  ['Content-Type', 'application/expect-ct-report+json'],
  ['Content-Type', 'application/xss-auditor-report'],
  ['Content-Type', 'application/ocsp-request'],
]
```

- [simple-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header)
- [cors-protocol-exceptions](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-exceptions)

Comment: *The only valid values [...]* Not exactly. For instance, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; whatever` is allowed.

Comment: `['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']` is in my answer listed as a  *simple-header*

Comment: Read my comment again. My point is that you can add anything after the semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to call an api and getting stuck with this in your react app you can add a proxy to the server and the cors error will get removed

just add this line at the package.json

```
"proxy":"url-to-your-server",
```