# Microsoft Academic Search API stopped working

Tags: cors, axios, fetch-api

I was using the [Microsoft Academic Search API](https://msr-apis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/academic-search-api/) successfully but for some reason my unchanged code stopped working roughly 2 weeks ago, not sure why. I nailed it down to some CORS issue: preflight `OPTIONS` requests lead to 404 and doing a direct `POST` with `mode: 'no-cors'` prevents the custom API-key header (`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`) from being sent, resulting in 401. I've never looked in the Networks dev-tab while everything was still working, maybe the OPTIONS requests still worked two weeks back? Or could it be a Firefox update on my side?

I've tried GET and POST requests, I've tried both axios and fetch APIs, I've tried both no-cors and cors requests. Nothing works except when manually adding the API-key to the header.

```js
// simple no-cors request
fetch(
    'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors', // I've tried removing this line for CORS request
        headers: new Headers(
           { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"[actual key not needed for replication]" }
        ),
        body: "expr=Id%3D2101196984&attributes=Id"
    }
).then( response => { console.log(response);} )
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

See how the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header is missing. After some research I've realized this is due to the `no-cors` mode ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837819/12220432)). Simple POST header:

```
Host: api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: null
Content-Length: 34
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

This request leads to 401, permission declined. Note I've used a dummy key in the example, but I'm getting the same issue with my real keys and it must be due to the omission of the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` because *when I resend the request after manually adding the key-header, the response works just fine* (using Firefox's "Edit and Resend" function in the Developer's Toolbar Network=>Headers Tab and manually adding a line `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: [actual key]`).

However, when I use a CORS request, the following OPTIONS preflight request can't really be handled by the server, returning 404.

Request OPTIONS header occurring when sending same fetch-request as above just without `mode: 'no-cors'`

```
Host: api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: ocp-apim-subscription-key
Origin: null
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Resource Not Found
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 10:59:03 GMT
```

Is anybody else experiencing this problem? Is there anything I can do or does this seem to be a server issue on Microsoft's side?

Comment: Looks like VOSviewer is having issues with the API as well since roughly 2 weeks ago, not sure if it's due to the same problem though: ["October 16, 2019. ... The Microsoft Academic API doesn't work at all."](https://www.vosviewer.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to say that the CORS issue should have finally been resolved. The issue itself was a result of misconfiguration during an internal migration.

Apologies for the delay in resolution!