# Fetch http POST request sending EMPTY object to Node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, fetch

I'm trying to make an HTTP Post request to my Node server from an html form. I use the Body Parser and everything but when I try to fetch the request, and log the req.body in my server, it's an EMPTY object. Do you know how I can fix this?

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
  const formData = { email, password };

  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    mode: 'no-cors'
  };

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/login', options)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Basically, the opposite of [Unable to fetch POST without no-cors in header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37668282/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said `mode: 'no-cors'` so everything that requires CORS permission is ignored (including setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`).

Remove `mode: 'no-cors'` (and use the [cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) on the server).