# call rest api post service from java script throws error

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

while call a post service from java script in console i am getting the below error

> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()**

and in my back end java eclipse ide got the below error

> **Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported**

how to resolve this error

thanks in advance

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="myclass">HELLO!WELCOME</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="loginform" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputphone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputpassword" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="forgot-password">
                <a href="">forgot password</a>
            </div>
           <input type="submit"value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.js"> </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

java script code:

```
var form = document.getElementById('loginform')

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var inputphoneno = document.getElementById("inputphone").value;
    var inputpassword = document.getElementById("inputpassword").value;
    
    const jdata = {
        "phonenumber":inputphoneno,
        "password":inputpassword
      };

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/myurl/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({jdata}),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        mode: "no-cors"
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            //return response.json();
            console.log(response)
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        })

})
```

Comment: Can you share the backend code

Comment: my back end code working fine while call from rest client

Comment: ok may be this is the issue
body: JSON.stringify({jdata})
Should be : JSON.stringify(jdata)

Comment: yes i tried but no use same error

Comment: you can't use `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` with `mode: 'no-cors'`, `text/plain` is being send instead and backend is refusing it. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668282/unable-to-fetch-post-without-no-cors-in-header.